# The call-stacktrace of TensorFlow source code?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, computer-vision, tensorflow, deep-learning

I want to study TensorFlow for a long time , so I want to read the source code of it , but at the beginning. For example :

[image: one of TF function]

I can’t find the deeper level of the function.

Where does the function `Shape` compute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code fragment that you have shown is an automatically generated piece of code that adds a `"Shape"` **operation** to the graph. The string `"Shape"` in the arguments to `_op_def_lib.apply_op()` determines the operation-type of the node. The standard operation types are registered in C++ source code, in the [`tensorflow/core/ops/`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/core/ops) directory of the TensorFlow source code. In particular, the `"Shape"` operation is registered in [`tensorflow/core/ops/array_ops.cc`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/ad4f02a69162abe5d242b7d94f62138849aec9ab/tensorflow/core/ops/array_ops.cc#L1440). These registrations are used to define the types of the inputs to, attrs of, and outputs from each operation, and the Python wrappers are generated from these registrations.

The first time you run a subgraph containing that node (i.e. in a call to `tf.Session.run()`), TensorFlow will look up the appropriate **kernel** that implements the operation on a particular device. (For example, there are often separate kernels for CPU and GPU implementations of operations.) The standard kernel implementations are registered in C++ source code, in the `tensorflow/core/kernels/` directory of the TensorFlow source code. In particular, the `"Shape"` kernels are registered in [`tensorflow/core/kernels/shape_ops.cc`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/ad4f02a69162abe5d242b7d94f62138849aec9ab/tensorflow/core/kernels/shape_ops.cc#L52). The kernel registration names a class the implements the kernel, which must be a subclass of [`tensorflow::OpKernel`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/ad4f02a69162abe5d242b7d94f62138849aec9ab/tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.h#L70), and in this case is the [`tensorflow::ShapeOp`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/ad4f02a69162abe5d242b7d94f62138849aec9ab/tensorflow/core/kernels/shape_ops.cc#L29) class. The constructor is called when the subgraph runs for the first time, and the `Compute()` method is called each time the operation runs.

Comment: Thank you .Please tell me where can I find these C++ file in my local machine? Thank you again.I search the whole filesystem and can not find them.So how to read the C++ source code efficient?

Comment: This depends on how you've configured your TensorFlow installation. If you installed from source, they will be in the location to which you cloned the [TensorFlow git repository](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow). If you installed from a PIP package, then the source files will probably not be on your local machine.